# Kivy - Add buttons dynamically with referring to root atributes

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivymd

so I try to break down my problem:

I have two screens and when I switch from one screen to the other it should dynamically generate buttons on the second screen (id: "**thema_screen**"). The buttons are created at the second screen into a GridLayout, which has the id: "**grid_thema_screen**"

Now I want the font_size of the buttons to change automatically, if I change the window size, which works pretty well with `font_size: min(root.height, root.width) / 10` in the **kivy-file**, but it's not working, when I write it in the **python-file** `add_widget(Button(text = str(i+2), font_size = min(self.root.height, self.root.width) / 2))`

It changes the font-size once, but then if I resice the window, the font isn't changing anymore. Here is the code snippet of my python file:

```
class Wurzel(MDBoxLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Wurzel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def changeScreen(self, next_screen):
    if next_screen == "thema_screen":
        self.ids.wurzel_screen_manager.current = next_screen

        for i in range(12):
            self.ids.thema_screen.ids.grid_thema_screen.add_widget(Button(text = str(i+2), font_size = min(self.root.height,
                                                                                          self.root.width) / 10))
```

And here my kivy File:

```
<Wurzel>:
orientation: 'vertical'
spacing: 20

MDToolbar:
    title: 'Hellllooo'
    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.navigation_klick()], ["apple", lambda x: app.navigation_klick()]]
    elevation: 8

ScreenManager:
    id: wurzel_screen_manager
    StartScreen:
        name: "start_screen"
    ThemaScreen:
        id: thema_screen
        name: "thema_screen"

<StartScreen@MDScreen>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

   ...

<ThemaScreen@MDScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        id: grid_thema_screen
        cols: 3

    padding: root.width * .01, root.height * .01
    spacing: min(root.width, root.height) * .02


    Button:
        text: "1"
        font_size: min(root.height, root.width) / 10
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.font_size*3, self.font_size*3
```

So it would be really nice, if someone could help me and tell me, why the fontsize isn't changing automatically anymore, if I create the buttons dynamically in Python.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why the font size doesn't change when you add the buttons programatically is because the `font_size` attribute is not bound to anything. When you create a widget in the kv file, the interpreter will automatically bind your properties to one another. This means that when you enter:

`font_size: min(root.height, root.width) / 10`

in the kv file, when `root.height` is updated, so is `font_size`. However, writing

`Button(font_size = min(self.root.height, self.root.width) / 2)`

in your Python file creates a Button whose `font_size` attribute is defined by the values you passed at that instance.

There are several things you could do, you could create `NumericProperty` in your `Wurzel` class and bind your Buttons to this property (see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html for more details). However, since your having the issues with resizing, I think the easiest thing to do is take advantage of the `on_size` call back (see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html for more details).

Here is what the `Wurzel` class should look like:

```
class Wurzel(MDBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wurzel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def changeScreen(self, next_screen):
        if next_screen == "thema_screen":
            self.ids.wurzel_screen_manager.current = next_screen

            for i in range(12):
                self.ids.thema_screen.ids.grid_thema_screen.add_widget(Button(text = str(i+2), font_size = min(self.root.height, self.root.width) / 10)) 

    def update_font_size(self, *args):
        for button in self.children:  # Loop through all children
            if isinstance(button, Button):  # Check if child is a button (may not need)
                button.font_size = min(self.root.height, self.root.width) / 10))  # Update font_size

    on_size = update_font_size  # Set a callback for on_size
```

Comment: Hello jda5, thanks a lot for yout answer. I understand and tried your code, but I am not sure about where to put the `on_size = update_font_size  # Set a callback for on_size` part. I tried to write `on_size: self.update_font_size()` in the kivy file under <Wurzel>: but it says "invalid data after declaration". Can you tell me, where to write that?

Comment: Update: I added it right under the "<Wurzel>:" and its also calling the update_font_size methode BUT it's not looping through all my buttons :( I think it is like that, because the buttons I created are children of the "thema_screen" widget and not of the Wurzel widget. Is that right? Is there a possibility to reach ALL the buttons?

Comment: I found a solution by reaching the children of the GridLayout (which are my buttons...)

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution with jda5 (thanks a lot to you!!!). I changed the method of @jda5 a bit:

```
   def update_font_size(self, *args):
    for button in self.ids.thema_screen.ids.grid_thema_screen.children:  # Loop through all children
        
        if isinstance(button, Button):  # Check if child is a button (may not need)
            button.font_size = min(self.height, self.width) / 20  # Update font_size
```

and after that I put the "on_size" callback to the kivy file like that:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: wurzel_screen_manager
    StartScreen:
        name: "start_screen"
    ThemaScreen:
        on_size: app.root.update_font_size()
        id: thema_screen
        name: "thema_screen"
```